# Java: Need to add the rolls of user-defined number of dice

Tags: java

New Computer Science major here, trying to figure something out. So, I am supposed to take a user-defined number of D6 and add the rolls together, along with a user-defined bonus (I think my professor is secretly a DnD fan...) to come up with a total. The only difficulty I am having is that my program is only adding the last roll and the bonus. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random roll = new Random();

        int rollValue = 0;
        int numDice = 0;
        int statBonus = 0;
        int totalRoll = 0;

        System.out.println("How many 6-sided die would you like to roll? ");
        numDice = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What number would you like to add to the rolls? ");
        statBonus = scan.nextInt();

        scan.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
        {
            rollValue = roll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("Roll is: " + rollValue);

        }
        totalRoll = statBonus + rollValue;

        System.out.println("The result of rolling " + numDice + " D6, and adding " + statBonus + " is: " 
    + totalRoll);
    }
}
```

Would be a massive help if someone could point me in the right direction! Thanks in advance!

--Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite this section:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
{
    rollValue = roll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("Roll is: " + rollValue);

}
totalRoll = statBonus + rollValue;
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
{
    rollValue = roll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println("Roll is: " + rollValue);
    totalRoll += rollValue;
}
totalRoll = statBonus + totalRoll;
```

In other words, keep a running total.

Comment: Amazing. I figured it out and came to edit the question, but you had already answered! What a beast! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Benjamin!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.